# checking which map view annotation is tapped on mkmapview

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I am having problem in knowing which annotation is tapped on MKMapView.

let me explain my problem, there is a simple view controller on which map view is loaded.

my annotation class "MapViewAnnotation.h" is as follows

```
@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *sID;
    NSString *zipCode;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *zipCode;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)titleOfPin andStoreId:(NSString *)storeIdForDetails andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinateOfPin andZipCode:(NSString *)zip;
```

here is my "MapViewAnnotation.m" file.

```
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize title, coordinate,storeId,zipCode;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)titleOfPin andStoreId:(NSString *)storeIdForDetails andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinateOfPin andZipCode:(NSString *)zip
{
    [super init];
    title = titleOfPin;
    coordinate = coordinateOfPin;
    sID = storeIdForDetails;
    zipCode = zip;
    return self;
}


-(void)dealloc
{
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

and this is my viewcontroller.m file

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    //I want to access the sID property of that annotation here. PLEASE HELP ME HOW CAN I DO THAT

    if (!storeDetailControllerObject) {
        storeDetailControllerObject = [[StoreDetailController alloc]init];
    }
    //    storeDetailControllerObject.storeId = [view.annotation storeId];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:storeDetailControllerObject animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MapViewAnnotation *mapViewAnnotation = (MapViewAnnotation*)view.annotation;
if( [mapViewAnnotation isKindOfClass:[MapViewAnnotation class]] ){
    storeDetailControllerObject.storeId = mapViewAnnotation.storeId;
}
```

Comment: it is not helping :( . App crashing after this. EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Comment: Could you give a little more information about why and where it is crashing?

Comment: i have added this line just after the if condition     `NSLog(@"Store id ------%@",storeDetailControllerObject.storeId);`
and getting bad access error at this line only

Comment: You should always be able to call storeDetailControllerObject.storeId if it is setup correctly. Is it a synthesized NSString?

Comment: no it was not. instead of wasting time on it i changed the storeID to int. that is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MKMapViewDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view;
```

If you handle the event in this method you may know which annotation was selected.
You have to set the MKMapView's delegate and to declare that you class implements the MKMapViewDelegate.